# Laravel FatalErrorException in Model.php line 827: Class not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Laravel. 
I have tried to use one example in my code, but as a result I got an error - `FatalErrorException in Model.php line 827: Class Category not found`.

Afterwards I have modified one line of code and fixed an error. However, I actually do not understand the reason of error and how I fixed it.

This is my code (as a result when I'm trying to build query using `category` - I am getting error):

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Category;

class Translation extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('lang1', 'lang2', 'lang1_code', 'lang2_code', 'category_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }        
}
```

However, when I modify one line, I do not get above error:

old line (error): `return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');`

new line (no error): `return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');`

Comment: which are the paths of `Category` and `Translation` file classes ?

Comment: Check the namepace of `Category`, but if left at the default, it should be `$this->belongsTo("App\Category", ...);`

Answer (score 2):

All your Models are normally stored in the App folder.

So for a relation you need to pass the full path to your Model, like

```
App\Category
```

Answer (score 2):

In the relation you must add the full path **before PHP 5.5**:

```
'App\Category'
```

**Since PHP 5.5**, the `class` keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using `ClassName::class`. This is particularly useful with namespaced classes.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Category;

class Translation extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('lang1', 'lang2', 'lang1_code', 'lang2_code', 'category_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }        
}
```